# jquery MMENU opened default

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles, mmenu

Anyone can help me how to display the navbar by default once the page loads? Currently the navbar hides, I just want to show the sidebar menu as a default. Thank you!

```
script - 
 $("#mmenu").mmenu({ navbar: !1 });

html-
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/mmenu/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/mmenu/js/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<nav id="mmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="logo-menu"></li>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="page">
<header>
  <a href="#mmenu" id="hamburger"><span class="top-bar"></span><span class="middle-bar"></span><span class="bottom-bar"></span></a>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</header></div>
```

Comment: add your code please

Comment: done, check now

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('put your id/class of the menu/nav').show();
    });`

**Example**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').show();
});
```

```css
#menu{
display:none;
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="menu">
menu
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: it works but it overlaps on the design of the page, the navbar display under the header and footer

Comment: to answer it please add your css... but basically u have to use `z-index`

Comment: Using the base css and js I too have the same problem where it overlaps the base content.